# Can a diode's ideality factor ever be less than 1?

Tags: diodes

Can the diode ideality factor be lesser than 1 or very close to 1?

[image]

- ID and VD are the diode current and voltage, respectively
- q is the charge on the electron
- n is the ideality factor
- k is Boltzmann’s  constant
- T is temperature in Kelvin

Comment: Where did the equation come from? What are D, S, q, VD, n, k and T?

Comment: @Transistor Looks like the [Shockley Diode Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shockley_diode_equation)... or was that something you wanted the OG to figure out? Lol woops

Answer (score 5):

The ideality factor adjusts the original Shockley diode equation to fit non-Germanium diodes more closely. There's also a series resistance term.

Equation 3.13 from the original 1950 paper from [Bell System Technical Journal](https://archive.org/stream/bellsystemtechni28amerrich#page/454):

[image]

The factor was added a few years later in a [fascinating paper](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1721579) on radioactive p-n junction power sources.

[image]

With silicon diodes the ideality factor is closer to 2 than 1. It can be higher than 2. A diode-connected silicon transistor operated at reasonable currents has an ideality factor close to 1.

I don't think it is ever less than 1 for a real diode, but that may not be correct.